How to create two widgets droppable in each other?
The idea is simple, imagine a Row with only two Containers side by side. One red and another blue.
If we wrap each Container with a Draggable we can now drag these containers.
But I want also to create a DragTarget in the same size and position of each container. So we can drag and drop the container blue for instance, in the red area and call a SetState() and render now the actual order.
We can use a list and reorder itens inside, here we have many options, no problens.
The point is: How can we put this DragTarget in front of a Container without block this container but kepping the drop method working from DragTarget?
Thank you!!!
Stack with draggable and dragtarget but if dragtarget is behind the container the drop method just no work and if we put in front we block the Container. Even with a Colors.transparent.

In what way does ReorderableList not do what you want?

Hi. Thank you. My point is about DragTarget and Draggable widgets. But you are right, we can also use ReorderableList to manage lists.
